# winston custom transport with typescript

Tags: typescript, winston

I'm having a hard time trying to get a winstom custom logger compiled using typescript.

I'm taking [this js](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#adding-custom-transports) code as starting point and taking into account [this comment](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/1382#issuecomment-401250573) from github:

```js
import * as Transport from 'winston-transport'

//
// Inherit from `winston-transport` so you can take advantage
// of the base functionality and `.exceptions.handle()`.
//
module.exports = class YourCustomTransport extends Transport {
  constructor(opts) {
    super(opts);
    //
    // Consume any custom options here. e.g.:
    // - Connection information for databases
    // - Authentication information for APIs (e.g. loggly, papertrail, 
    //   logentries, etc.).
    //
  }

  log(info, callback) {
    setImmediate(() => {
      this.emit('logged', info);
    });

    // Perform the writing to the remote service
    callback();
  }
};
```

But I get the error:

```
Type 'typeof TransportStream' is not a constructor function type.ts(2507)
```

I tried with several alternatives but always end up blocked by typescript compiler.

Comment: I'm running into similar issues.  Did you resolve it?

Answer (score 14):

When I replace your import statement with

```typescript
 import Transport = require('winston-transport');
```

then *tsc* has no complaints.  This is similar to how the built-in [file transport](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/a910c284fe8c028f4a64f30790821f4303e1c7c3/lib/winston/transports/file.js#L17-L27) imports *winston-transport*.

Comment: This answer should be accepted.  Fixed a very frustrating problem!!

Answer (score 8):

In case anyone still need this.

Don't forget to install 'winston-transport' as it is not a part of standard winston library.

`npm i winston-transport`

```
import Transport from 'winston-transport';
import { createLogger } from 'winston';

class CustomTransport extends Transport {
  constructor(opts) {
    super(opts);
  }
  log(info, callback) {
 // do whatever you want with log data
    callback();
  }
};


// Using transport
const transport = new CustomTransport({});

// Create a logger and consume an instance of your transport
const logger = createLogger({
  transports: [transport]
});

// Use logger
logger.info('Here I am');
```